# What is the best framework and difference of nodejs framework

Tags: node.js, express, faye

These days I try to develop real time application using nodejs.
That application want to update the dashboard according to api data.

I installed express and faye and try to compare what is the best and what are the differences of that two.
As I know express is a node base framework and faye is a subscriber/publisher based one.

But I think both are almost same and anyone can help me to identify the differences?
What is fast and what can be done using the frameworks like that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not very comparable. If you want to create a real-time application, you will probably need to use both.

Express is a web framework. You will need it to serve and handle HTTP requests and responses. It will help you handle things like url routing, request/response handling middleware, interfacing with template engines, etc... Express is as fast as you'll get.

Faye is a pub sub messaging system- It will not be capable of handling standard HTTP requests and responses. You may be able to implement a live stream of the data using Faye, however, you will still have the need to serve up your client side application using Express.

I would also look into Socket.io as an alternative to Faye-  in addition to Express.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think it is better use both Socket.io and Express to manage real time data.Am I right?

Comment: Yea, I've used express and socket.io to create a real-time dashboard before. Express served up the html, js, css, images, and other assets. The streaming data was done using socket.io.